# Python Django - How to Pass HTTPS URL as function parameter in manage.py shell

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to call a function insert_db in the python shell. insert_db requires an https url to call some other functions.

In Terminal in my Django python project folder, I type './manage.py shell' to get the python shell for Django going.

After that:

```
>>> from send_values.api.send_to_db import insert_db
>>> insert_db('https://www.encodeproject.org/search/?searchTerm=H3K4ME3&type=Experiment&replication_type=isogenic&assembly=GRCh38&award.rfa=ENCODE4&format=json')
```

I'm getting the following error:

**requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'h': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://h?**

send_to_db.py code:

```
# python send_to_db.py 'https://www.encodeproject.org/search/?searchTerm=H3K4ME3&type=Experiment&replication_type=isogenic&assembly=GRCh38&award.rfa=ENCODE4&format=json'

from ..models import Correlations
from .lambda_async_s3_uri import filter_complete
import sys

def insert_db(args):

    print(args)

    table_values = filter_complete(args)

    for value_set in table_values:
        new_value_set = Correlations.objects.create(value_set)
        # new_value_set = Correlations.objects.create(experimentName=item[3], colLabel=item[5], rowLabel=item[4], rowNum=item[0], colNum=item[1], cor=item[2])
        new_value_set.save()

def main(args):
    insert_db(args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if you need more information.

Notes:

1) I know the insert_db function works like it is supposed to (taking the url, downloading some files, parsing through them for some data, and making some calculations from that data). Before making this Django project, in a pure Python project, I used to call it like this:
python send_to_db.py 'https://www.encodeproject.org/search/?searchTerm=H3K4ME3&type=Experiment&replication_type=isogenic&assembly=GRCh38&award.rfa=ENCODE4&format=json'
At that earlier point, instead of trying to add it to the Django database, I was just printing the values insert_db would calculate (which it successfully outputted in the terminal). Passing the url through the terminal with this bash command worked then, and I'm wondering how to do this in a python.

2) I also tried the following in ./manage.py shell:

```
>>> from send_values.api.send_to_db import insert_db
>>> url = 'https://www.encodeproject.org/search/?searchTerm=H3K4ME3&type=Experiment&replication_type=isogenic&assembly=GRCh38&award.rfa=ENCODE4&format=json'
>>> insert_db(url)
```

But I still get the same error:

**requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'h': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://h?**

Comment: You should read how to create custom [management](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/08/27/how-to-create-custom-django-management-commands.html) commands, an [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) is the official docs about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a wild guess - I didn't check what `filter_complete()` is supposed to do -, but given what your working code looks like and the error message, it seems it expects a list or tuple, not a string. If that's right, you should call it this way:

```
>>> from send_values.api.send_to_db import insert_db
>>> url = 'https://www.encodeproject.org/search/?searchTerm=H3K4ME3&type=Experiment&replication_type=isogenic&assembly=GRCh38&award.rfa=ENCODE4&format=json'
>>> # make the argument a list
>>> insert_db([url])
```

If this solves the issue, you may then want to update your code to use `*varargs` instead:

```
from ..models import Correlations
def insert_db(*args):
    print(args)
    table_values = filter_complete(args)
    for value_set in table_values:
        new_value_set = Correlations.objects.create(value_set)
        new_value_set.save()

def main(*args):
    insert_db(*args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
```

And then you can call it as expected:

```
>>> insert_db('https://some.url.here')
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I forgot filter_complete expects a list since it calls another function down the line which takes in the parameter args[0]. Very helpful!

Comment: This is actually the most common typing issue with Python - passing a string (which is an iterable) to a function that expects a list / tuple / whatever iterable of strings. Hopefully the symptoms are usually rather easy to spot (in your case the error message was a sure sign) when you've dealt with it a couple times already ;-)